# how to replace TOWER 2_3_C with T2_C using Preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace my string using preg_replace. I want to replace:

> TOWER 2_3_C

with

> T2_C

Actually I want to get the first letter and remove the second number with its under score. 
To do this I used:

```
return preg_replace('/([A-Z]). * ? (. * ?)_(.*?)_(.*?)/', '$1$2-$4', $a);
```

but it does not work.

Any Idea??

Comment: `([A-Z]).+\s(\d).+(_[A-Z])` ?? https://regex101.com/r/kH1jD7/1

Comment: @Chris you are always helpful. I wanted to ask another question if you do not mind. I have string like this: Tower 2-3-C which I want to be T2-C. beside of that,  Can I say if it was Main-1-c or Medical-1-C or Maiil-1-C return "Main". it is too many rules and I confused. I appreciate if you can help me a little bit

Comment: @MortezaSahebkar you can use the `|` to allow for variations of the `M` words. `M(ain|edical|aiil)-1-c` then replace with `Main-1-c`, I'd think. You also can always ask more questions just show what you have, what you tried, and what you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should accomplish that. Given the string though you may want to make this stricter.

```
$string = 'TOWER 2_3_C';
echo preg_replace('/([A-Z]).*?(\d+?_).*?([A-Z])/', '$1$2$3', $string);
```

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/iX9dP5/1

This isn't `remove the second number with its under score`. This finds an `A-Z`, anything until a number, (make it `\d` if you only want a single placed value) the next underscore, then anything until the first `A-Z`. This is case sensitive currently use the `i` modifier or add `a-z` to the character classes.

In your regex you have issues with whitespace. For example:

```
. * ?
```

The `.` is a single character, the `&#160;*` is zero or more white spaces, and the `&#160;?` is an optional whitespace (can't get whitespaces to show up in code highlights for some reason, `&#160;` is the whitespace entity). The quantifier needs to be the preceding character for it to quantify that character.

Comment: Can you explain how it doesn't work? or give an example? https://eval.in/497750 Maybe your description isn't accurate. Your replacement string has a `-` in it but your text says you want `T2_C` (no `-`).

Comment: I see it works on eval.in but it does not work on my code. that is really strange .

Comment: Make a reproducible example on eval of how your code is using it.

Comment: @MortezaSahebkar what is the status here?

Comment: Chris, thank you very much for guidance. your codes perfectly worked. My problem was I used $string['a'] instead of $string["a"].

Comment: do you have any Idea if I want to create letter B from "housing station B" or "station B" or anything before letter B?? I just want to extract letter after station and remove rest of the string.

Comment: You could use `.*station B`. Which would find anything before `station B`... If you `B` is a varying character your can use `.` there and capture it with `()`... so maybe `.*station (.)` then `$1` will have your match.

Comment: Awesome. Regexp like Chinese to me and I really have hard time to understand them.